# Find phrases using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search, phrases

I am working on a project and I need your suggestions in a database query. I am using PHP and MySQL.

**Context**

- I have a table named `phrases` containing a `phrases` column in which there are phrases stored, each of which consists of one to three words.
- I have a `text` string which contains 500 - 1000 words

I need to highlight all the phrases in the `text` string which exist in my `phrases` database table.

**My solution**

I go through every phrase in the phrase list and compare it against the `text`, but the number of phrases is large (100k) so it takes about 2 min or more to do this matching.

Is there any more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Could you pre-match the text and cache it somewhere ahead of time?  Then it won't feel slow to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna focus on how to do the comparision part with 100K Values.  This will require two steps.

a) Write a C++ library and link it to PHP using an extension. Google PHP-CPP. There is a framework which allows you to do this.

b) Inside C/C++ , you need to create a data structure which has a time complexity of O(n) . n being length of the phrases you're searching for. Normally, this is called a tries data structure. This is conventionally used for words without space[not phrases]. but, surely you can write your own.

Here is a link, which contains the word implementation. aka dictionary. 
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/

This takes quite a bit of Memory since, the number is 100K. fair to say, you need a large system. But, when you're looking for better performance, then, Memory tends to be a tradeoff.

**Alternative Approach**
Only PHP. Here , extract phrases from your text input. Convert them into a Hash. the table data that you contain, should also be stored in a hash. [Needs Huge Memory].  The performance here will be rocket fast, per search aka O(1). so, for a sentence of k words. your time complexity will be O(K-factorial).